# Roundcube vcard Import Not Working

Tags: vcard

I am trying to import contacts to RoundCube version 0.82 address book, on a Dreamhost server, with no plugins installed.

Every time I get the message "Successfully imported 0 contacts."

I have tried different vcard versions, tested out changing lots of the fields and nothing has worked so far.

Here is an example of a completely stripped vcard file that fails to work:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
EMAIL;INTERNET: test@test.com
END:VCARD
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there cannot be spaces after the colons in the vcard.  I did replace all the ': ' with ':' and my complete import worked.

For the given example this now worked:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
EMAIL;INTERNET:test@test.com
END:VCARD
```